# Double.TryParse shows wrong result

Tags: c#, double

I have a string which comes from database. For example it is 5.1 . I want to convert this string to double with double.tryparse() method. I expect the result will be 5.1, but it is not. The result seems like 5.0999999999999996. What can I do to achieve this so that it will be 5.1?

Comment: Whis is it a `varchar` in database and not a `float`/`decimal`? Or are you using code like `row["ColumnName"].ToString()` instead of `row.Field<double>("ColumnName")`?

Comment: The value 5.1 cannot be represented exactly in type `double`. Why are you using `double` instead of `decimal`?

Comment: try to convert as decimal, more precise

Comment: You should read about IEEE floats, and how they work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: **1.** Note re: terminology in your question's title: `double.TryParse` does not *show* anything. It merely converts one value into another. Chances are that you are looking at that method's return value either via `Console.WriteLine`, `MessageBox.Show`, or Visual Studio's Watch / Auto / Locals window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of double, do :

```
decimal.TryParse(s, out myDecimal);
```

or

```
 decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(s);
```

Because decimal is floating decimal point instead of floating binary.
Here's a great explanation : [Difference between double and decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Comment: Any explanation why his code fails would be really nice to know for the author.

Comment: It's done... downvoting was not really necessary ...

Comment: I am so sorry, I did it accidentally. The solution is worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3894737 You can't "un-downvote", but you can change to an upvote

Comment: And mark solution as answer if it fix your problem ;-)

Comment: VO-ote up requires 15 reputation. So, I am not able to do this.

Comment: Is this ok? now, it writes 0